# Escaping forward slashes in an strpos() declaration

Tags: php, strpos

I have the following code to set a variable, `$lang`, depending on what directory we are currently in:

```
$find_lang = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos('$find_lang', '/fr/') !== false) {
    $lang = "fr";
}
else if (strpos('$find_lang', '/de/') !== false) {
    $lang = "de";
}
else {
    $lang = "en";
}
echo $lang;
parse_ini_file($lang . ".ini");
```

However, echoing `$lang` always gives me "en", even if I'm in http://example.com/fr/. I believe it's because of the forward slashes around the directory, but I've tried escaping as follows: `//fr//` and `\/fr\/` but neither gives me a different answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's much simpler - remove quotes around $find_lang from `strpos('$find_lang',` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $find_lang = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if (strpos($find_lang, '/fr/') !== false) {
     $lang = "fr";
   }
   else if (strpos($find_lang, '/de/') !== false) {
      $lang = "de";
   }
   else {
     $lang = "en";
   }
    echo $lang;
   parse_ini_file($lang . ".ini");
```

Comment: Thank you, and the same to S. Korolev... such a rookie mistake!